# SQLite + rails - working the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I ended up in a situation where I have a relatively large table, and I need to add a new column to it. Sounds easy enough? Well, there is a catch - I also need to fill that new column with data based on data already present, but I have no idea how to automate this process.

I have columns 'title' and 'title_de', and new column is 'lang'. New column should contain either 'de' or 'eng' depending on if 'title' is blank or not (blank 'title' means it's 'de', non blank means it's 'eng').

How to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do something like this:

```
class AddColumnToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :items, :lang, :string
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      Item.all.each do |item|
        item.lang = "de"
        item.lang = "eng" unless item.title.blank?
        item.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I hope that solves your problem!

Comment: Getting this error `undefined method 'each' for #<Class:0x5e92240>`

Comment: `Item.all.each`

Comment: changed `item.lang = "eng" unless item.title.nil?` to `item.lang = "eng" unless item.title.blank?` and as suggested above use `Item.all.each`, worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks, made the changes!